# Как получить значение ввода с клавиатуры до нажатия enter?

Tags: excel, vba

Как получить вводимый текст с клавиатуры в ячейку до нажатия enter (до того как текст оказался в ячейке).

Comment: Пока ячейка находитя в режиме редактирования, макосы не работают. Уточните вопрос.